# Dialog start only the first time on startup?

Tags: java, android, startup, android-alertdialog

I tried to make a dialog on startup of my application like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Hi Stackoverflow!").create().show();
}
```

But I want to make it so that if I click a checkbox in the dialog "Don't show again" then the second time I start the application the dialog doesn't appear. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you got the checkbox in your `Dialog` yet?

Comment: nope, i never use the dialog. It's the first time

Comment: See my answer. That should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences for this. Add a flag that tells you if the dialog has been shown before (or if the app has been launched before) and determine from there whether to show the dialog or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a `Dialog` with a `Button` then you don't really need an `AlertDialog`. You can simply create a `Dialog`, create a `layout` for the `Dialog` in xml with the `CheckBox` and `Button`, then use `setContentView()` on the `Dialog`.

To not show the `Dialog` again simply create a `boolean` variable and use `onCheckedChanged()` to set that variable to `true` if the checkbox is checked. Save that in `SharedPreferences` and check that value on start up.

[Good example of getting started with SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[SharedPreferences complete docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)